# How can I add rows to this HTML table dynamically...?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am making a game for class and I have a leaderboards page. What I am wanting to do is dynamically add a new row to the table every time a new result is added to the database.

This is my PHP `SELECT *`:

```
<?php $records = array();

if ($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user_settings, leaderboards")) {
    if ($results->num_rows) {
while ($row = $results->fetch_object()) { 
    $records[] = $row; 
}
$results->free(); 
    }
}
?>

<?php foreach ($records as $data) { ?>
...
```

My table looks like this:

```
<table class="leaderboard">
<tr>
<th>ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Robot Name</th><th>Power Remaining</th><th>Level</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo escape($data->id); ?></td><td><?php echo escape(htmlentities($data->first_name)); ?></td><td><?php echo escape(htmlentities($data->last_name)); ?></td><td><?php echo escape(htmlentities($data->robot_name)); ?></td><td><?php echo escape($data->power_remaining); ?></td><td><?php echo escape($data->level) ?></td>

</tr>
<tr>

</tr>
</table>
```

This successfully grabs the value from the database however how can I dynamically add a new record to the HTML table every time a new value is entered into the database?

Comment: Wouldn't you just loop for each TR not a whole new TABLE?

Comment: You need a loop statement in PHP like `while`, `for` or `foreach`. Then foreach record, you should output via echo or directly via response one `tr` with record's contents in `td`'s. It seems you are doing it currently.

Comment: You'll need to use Javascript. Make a URL that returns the records as JSON. Request the URL every minute. If there are new records, add a row in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `<td>` in the `foreach` with a simple echo in PHP, its should work.

For example:

```
<?php foreach ($records as $data) {
  echo "<td>  escape($data->id) ... </td>"
} ?>
```

Comment: Give an example, related to the questions code. He is using `foreach` already.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check current result count with Ajax every some time period, for ex. every minute. If there is more results - send them to client side and add them to table with javascript.